# SSL Certificate Issues when use WSO2 AWS Cloudformation stack

Tags: wso2, aws-cloudformation

During Cloudformation process, I got the following error:

Certificate 'arn:aws:iam::409486064609:server-certificate/EXAMPLE' not found (Service: AmazonElasticLoadBalancingV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: CertificateNotFound; Request ID: 24ba2810-a815-11e9-a888-8b9ad7cb576b)

I have a Certificate in place, but apparently when the process is creating or installing on load balancer, found an error and stop the process.

Any idea how to proceed?

Sirech

Comment: I can't find an answer to this - the closest I've got is that you can get this error for little while after the certificate has been created, but my certificate has been in AWS for more than a month and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: Actually it looks like it might be because the certificate is in a different region to the resource you're trying to attach it to.